# How to specify AxesOrigin for DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I would like to generate a plot with the y axis on the graph. In a "normal" numeric plot I do this using the AxesOrigin option. How to I specify the crossing point in a DateListPlot?

Here's the MWE of a DateListPlot graph. In this example I would like the y axis to cross the x axis at 4/20. How do I specify the crossing coordinates?

```
data = RandomInteger[100, 50];
DateListPlot[data, {2020, 3, 1}, ImageSize -> {500, 500}, 
PlotStyle -> Red, DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "Day"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your data only goes up to April 19.  So is the question how to move the vertical scale from the left edge to the right edge?  That would be done with something like `FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}`

Comment: Thanks for you help. 

Sorry about the 4/20 - I was trying to get to the end of the axis. Your solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Table[DateListPlot[Range[10], {2007},
AxesOrigin -> {"July 1, " <> ToString[2006 + i], 0}, Axes -> True,
Frame -> False], {i, 1, 10}]

[image: DateListPlot with moving x-axis based on AxesOrigin]